# Method for disabling a jquery sortable while awaiting an ajax update?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery sortable with an ajax callback tied to the update event.  The ajax callback sends the updated sort order back to the server and then does a refresh of the sortable to guarantee that the client and server are both in sync.

The problem I am having is that the user can start a new sortable event before the ajax call has completed - I'd like to prevent that.

What I did try doing was disabling the sortable on the update event, and then re-enabling it when the ajax call returned.  However unless I messed up the sequence, this didn't seem to work - I can still start a new sortable drag while the ajax call is still active.

Is there any other way to prevent this?  I can certainly set a global javascript variable that says, "hey not right now, I'm ajaxing..." and reference it, but I'm not sure what sortable event would check for this, or how it would kill the sortable click request.

Thoughts?

Comment: One thing I am suspicious of is whether you can disable a sortable that is currently active.  In other words, can I disable a sortable inside it's own update method?

Comment: this is a super old question now, but do you remember whether you tried `element.sortable('option', 'disabled', 'true')` instead of `element.sortable('disable')`? if so, did it have any more effect than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overlay a transparent absolutely-positioned div over the whole list, which will prevent any clicks/drags on the list.

Set it in your CSS to `display: none`. Then, when you initiate an AJAX call, set it to `display: block`, and when your AJAX call completes, switch it back to `display: none`.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned that I already have a small "Please wait..." display that shows up on a drug item.  What you are suggesting would work though in that it would essentially put a shield over the entire list.

Comment: I ended up using this method, though I see it as somewhat of a kludge.  It seems to me that one should be able to effectively disable and enable a sortable for this kind of case, but direct calls to disable the sortable (via jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-disable) seemed to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 3):

For a better user experience...

Instead of disabling the interface, you should cancel the previous ajax request so that it doesn't overwrite any new requests.

This keeps the interface responsive, fluid and flexible.
It allows the user to 'change their mind' and reorder the list while waiting for it to save.
Any old requests are cancelled and therefore don't overwrite new requests...

```
    //keep track of ajax request to allow cancellation of requests:
    var ajaxRequest = null;

    $('ul.sortable').sortable({
        containment: 'parent',
        update: function (event, ui) {

            //display your loading anim gif

            //get list of ids in correct order:
            var ids = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();

            //cancel any previous ajax requests:
            if (ajaxRequest) {
                ajaxRequest.abort();
            }

            //post order to web service:
            ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'somewebservice.blah',
                data: ids,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    //saved ok:
                    ajaxRequest = null;

                    //hide your loading anim gif
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the disabled property ?

```
$('#sortable').sortable('option', 'disabled', true )
```

And then after the ajax request

```
$('#sortable').sortable('option', 'disabled', false )
```

Comment: I didn't explicitly disable/enable using that call, but rather with 

$('.my-list').sortable('enable');

and

$('.my-list').sortable('disable');

Comment: Oh looking at the API, i don't think what you are using is the correct usage. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-disabled. What you seem to be doing is re initializing it, also the arguments need to be an object and not string.

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-disable though for disabling/enabling via method.  I just added a comment above, but can a sortable disable itself inside it's own update event handler?